# How can I make the tkinter canvas refresh?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I am trying to make a digital clock in python, I think I did everything right but the Canvas isn't refreshing so it just stays on 1 position.

```
import tkinter
import datetime

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()

t = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time = t.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5]
hour = t.hour
minute = t.minute
second = t.second
mc = t.microsecond
micro = mc/100000
print(current_time)

def tick():
    global current_time, micro, second, minute, hour
    micro += 1
    canvas.after(100, tick)
    if micro > 9:
        second += 1
        tick
    if second > 59:
        minute += 1
        tick
    if minute > 59:
        hour += 1
        tick
    if hour > 23:
        hour = 0
        tick

clock = canvas.create_text(320, 240, font="arial 72", text=current_time)
canvas.itemconfig(clock, text=current_time)

canvas.mainloop()
```

Can I do it like this or do I need to label the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reconfigure the canvas item whenever you want it to change (eg: `canvas.itemconfigure(clock, text=...)`). Also, you have to call `tick` once to start the loop.

For a simple clock, there's no need to calculate the hours, minutes and seconds. It is simpler to just ask python for the current time each time the function is called.

Example:

```
import tkinter
import datetime

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=640, height=480)
canvas.pack()

def tick():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time = t.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5]
    canvas.itemconfigure(clock, text=current_time)
    canvas.after(100, tick)

clock = canvas.create_text(320, 240, font="arial 72")
tick()

canvas.mainloop()
```